# Convert JSON to XML and save XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, json, json.net

I am trying to convert some JSON to XML and then save it using JSON.NET in C# but i can't seem to get it.

Here is what i have:

```
using System.XML;
using Newtonsoft;

XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("json.xml", null);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
doc.Save(writer);
```

Comment: What isn't working? Any errors? Exceptions?

Comment: I found one exception.

`A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.dll`

Comment: That means it was caught and handled by `Json.NET`. You still didn't explain what doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't save the XML file and i'm unsure if it even converts the JSON to XML.

Comment: Have you stepped into the code? Did you inspect the different variables? Debugging is your friend.

Comment: doc returned null but json was correct.

Comment: writer seems to also be null.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the deserializer. Make certain the Json _is_ valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and it works totally fine for me. According to the documentation for [`DeserializeXmlNode`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ConvertingJSONandXML.html) this should definitely work:

```
// { "?xml": { "@version": "1.0", "@standalone": "no" }, "root": { "person": [ { "@id": "1", "name": "Alan", "url": "http://www.google.com" }, { "@id": "2", "name": "Louis", "url": "http://www.yahoo.com" } ] } }
string json = "{ \"?xml\": { \"@version\": \"1.0\", \"@standalone\": \"no\" }, \"root\": { \"person\": [ { \"@id\": \"1\", \"name\": \"Alan\", \"url\": \"http://www.google.com\" }, { \"@id\": \"2\", \"name\": \"Louis\", \"url\": \"http://www.yahoo.com\" } ] } }";

System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDocument = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter("json.xml", null);
xmlTextWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
xmlDocument.Save(xmlTextWriter);

//<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
//<root>
//  <person id="1">
//    <name>Alan</name>
//    <url>http://www.google.com</url>
//  </person>
//  <person id="2">
//    <name>Louis</name>
//    <url>http://www.yahoo.com</url>
//  </person>
//</root>
```

Test your method with the JSON string above, to verify if it works. I would say you are having a problem with your JSON not being valid.

You can validate your JSON for example here:

- [The JSON Validator](http://www.jsonlint.com/)